# Perl Cron Job doesn't work

Tags: perl, cron

First, I:

```
 sudo crontab -e -u adrian
```

Then I add:

```
 * * * * * cd /home/adrian/app/; perl -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ script/db/log_to_db.pl
```

This should make the script run every minute. This script modifies the database with new data.
So I check my database every minute. No data. The "last update" time column doesn't change either. I check the log. Every minute this log appears:

```
 Jul  9 13:32:01 dev1 CROND[28658]: (adrian) CMD (cd /home/adrian/app/; perl -I   /home/adrian/app/lib/ script/db/log_to_db.pl)
```

Which looks like a succesful log. But the database doesn't change so the script is not running. Furthermore, if I execute the line on my command line manually:

```
  cd /home/adrian/app/; perl -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ script/db/log_to_db.pl
```

The database changes and the script runs without problem! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: cron usually sends mail to the account holder when a job fails to run. Have you checked for a message?

Comment: @Karthik T Yes because the "-I /home/adrian/app/lib/" tells where the libraries are and then the "script/db/log_to_db.pl" tells the script path to be run.

Comment: @adriancdperu ah my bad, skipped the `-I`.

Comment: Does the script depend on any environment variables, like `PATH` to find programs that it runs? `cron` doesn't execute your profile, so no environment variable customization is done.

Comment: @Barmar it needs the modules in /home/adrian/app/lib/ which is why I add the -I thingie. maybe this -I ... is causing the job not to happen?

Comment: You can check whether the `-I` is the problem by simply running the cron command by hand.

Comment: @Ted Hopp when I run the commnad by hand, i get no errors

Comment: `-I` is fine. The question is whether it depends on anything else in your normal login environment.

Comment: @Barmar it depends on "PLACK_ENV=development" set of environmental variables, which I have added to the top of the crontab file

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=adrian@gmail.com
HOME=/home/adrian/app/
PLACK_ENV=development

* * * * * adrian cd /home/adrian/apollo/; perl -I /home/adrian/apollo/lib/ script/db/game_play_log_to_db.pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the command runs fine from the command line, the problem is most likely some missing environment variable(s). Instead of running perl directly from the cron job, run a wrapper script that sets up the environment and then runs perl. Something like this should work (assuming you log in with bash—adjust as needed):

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/adrian/.bash_profile
cd /home/adrian/app/
perl -I /home/adrian/app/lib/ script/db/log_to_db.pl
```

Comment: just for confirming, your method went well! Thanks

Comment: `source cd`? Was that on purpose?

Comment: @innaM - That was a typo. Thanks for the catch.